# What are the different ways to claim that there does not exist any homomorphism between two groups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

I have been working on the problems on homomorphism, the problem encountered is

From the additive group $\mathbb{Q}$ to which one of the following groups does there exist a
non-trivial group homomorphism?

(A) $(\mathbb{R},×)$, the multiplicative group of non-zero real numbers.

(B) $\mathbb{Z}$ , the additive group of integers

(C) $\mathbb{Z_2}$, the additive group of integers modulo 2

(D) $(\mathbb{Q},×)$, the multiplicative group of non-zero rational numbers.

For option A ,I could directly think of $$ f: (\mathbb{Q},+) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},×) $$ as $$f(x)=e^x ; x \in \mathbb{Q} $$
Which is a homomorphism and being the question is single correct,I was done. But I am unable to claim that other options are incorrect, and I thought that if I am unable to find a function, that doesn't mean that it "does not exist".
There are several ways to prove the given function is a homomorphism but I want to find the ways to claim that the given groups are not homomorphic. I can think of the following;

**1** Homomorphic image of a cyclic group is cyclic.(it's counter statement, that if co-domain group is non cyclic and domain is cyclic then no "non-trivial homomorphism".

**2** Under some homomorphism from a group G to G', the normal subgroup H of G, can be made kernel. ( From this it can concluded that if I map a normal subgroup H to Identity element of G' then that that mapping should be a homomorphism(having doubt in this statement)).
And this would be very long process and it's based on just hit and trials.

**Question**

> Is there any systematic way to claim that there does not exist any non trivial homomorphism between the given two groups?

Comment: This is very vague.  As you probably know, there isn't a universal way to determine if a group, given by generators and relations, is trivial or not.  Of course, the more you know about the groups involved, the more you can say.  But universal methods tend to not exist in this context.

Comment: @DeepakKumar, I think you would not have had these questions if you had noticed that (1) the group $\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible, but the groups B,C,D are not; (2) the homomorphic image of a divisible group is a divisible group.

Comment: @kabenyuk I don't know about divisible groups

Comment: We are talking about the following property of the group $\mathbb{Q}$ for any integer $n>0$ and any $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ there exists $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $nx=a$.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. In what way is it unfocused? There is a single question right at the end, and the first part of the post is providing context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the "systematic way" that you are looking for  to show that there is no nontrivial homomorphism $G \to H$ is to identify a group-theoretical property $\mathcal{P}$ that is preserved under group homomorphisms, which  $G$ has but which no nontrivial subgroup of $H$ has.

As kabenyuk pointed out in comments, $G$ has the property (called divisibility) that, for every $g \in G$ and every integer $n>0$, there exists $h$ in $G$ with $nh=g$.

No nontrivial subgroup of any of the groups in (B), (C) and (D) has this property. This is clear for (B) and (C), and any nontrivial subgroup of $({\mathbb Q}\setminus \{0\},\times)$ has an element with no $n$-th root fpr some $n$.